# Apache Camel - http Producer don't use GET-Method with enrich Pattern

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I have a RESTful Webservice which I want to use with a content enricher in a Camel-Route.
See this similar Code:

```
from("direct:in") // Here comes XML
    .to("validator:something.xsd") // validate it
    .unmarshal("something-jaxb") // put it into a POJO
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://localhost:12345/restws/${header.foo}")) // Create the dynamic URI with simple
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET")) // set the HTTP-Method to use
    .enrich("http://dummy", new MyAggregator()) // fetch some Information from a Restful Webservice
    .to("direct:out"); // send the Message to another route
```

If I run this, I get the following error:

`No type converter available to convert from type: de.my.Class to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value de.my.Class@620ee765.`

It seems to me, he tries to send the body of the Exchange to the http-Endpoint, although I set the HTTP-Method to GET. I've read the documentation (https://camel.apache.org/http.html) and below **Calling using GET or POST** it describes that the Algorithm which selects the Method first look at the Header (1. Use method provided in header).

I found some workarounds, which describes how to move the body to a Exchange-property and move it back again after the Webservice-Call, but this can't be it...

---

EDIT:

- Like *Claus Ibsen* mentioned enrich doesn't support dynamic uris. Fixed this in the example!

Answer (score 1):

Neither enrich nor pollEnrich supports dynamic uris for their endpoints. Instead of using enrich, you can use the recipient list which support dynamic uris, and the aggregation strategy as well.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I fixed it (see above), but the problem stays the same :(.

Answer (score 0):

What's in the pojo? Your GET parameter should be a resource identifier and query parameters. That requires a custom converter.

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/rest/RESTIntro.html

maybe consider using restlet instead... it's easier I think.

http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

Comment: The Pojo is full of Lists of more Pojo's :). There are no query parameters in this Http-Request and I thought the endpoint uses the resource identifier which I just have written into the "enrich" Method (http:// localhost:12345/restws/${header.foo}).

Answer (score 0):

If it's "full of lists" of resources, sounds like you would want to split the lists and do a get on each resource

Comment: No. I just want to do **ONE** HTTP-Request with the value _foo_ in the Message Header. The Response of this Request should be merged with the Body after the Request.

Comment: So you want to pass a list of resources? You can do that but your API has to support it.